# Google Drive API Files.List() Error invalid_grant Bad Request

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using Google Apis Drive v3 with a simple request to find a folder with a specific ID and then to list all of the files in the folder.

However on request Execute it is creating the exception:

```
“Error: invalid_grant, Description: Bad Request, Uri:”
```

It used to work but has stopped sometime in the last month approx. while I was working on another project.

I have checked the API console and our Client ID is registered (I have hashed out the ID, Secret & refresh token) and everything seems OK with the creation of a service it is sending the request that is not working.

However the query used to work and I have tried changing the query and it still does not work.

Code is below, any suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated. Thanks

#### Request File List

```
    List<File> fileList = new List<File>();
        List<File> FileList_Lst_Ordered = new List<File>();
        try
        {
            string pageToken = null;
            do
            {
                request.Q = "'" + folderId + "' in parents";
                //request.Q = String.Format("name='{0}'", "Release Scripts Folder");
                //request.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' + title='" + folderId +"'";

                request.Spaces = "drive";
                request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, trashed)";
                request.PageToken = pageToken;

                var result = request.Execute();

                // Iterate through files
                foreach (File file in result.Files)
                {
                    // If it is a matching type (or we are retreiving all files)
                    if (!(bool)file.Trashed && (file.MimeType == type || type == "ALL"))
                    {
                        fileList.Add(file);
                    }

                    //RST_00001
                    else if (!(bool)file.Trashed && (file.MimeType == "sql" || file.MimeType == "text/x-sql"))
                    {
                        fileList.Add(file);
                    }
                }

                // Increment file token
                pageToken = result.NextPageToken;
            } while (pageToken != null);

            //RST_00002: Order List Alphabetically
            int Counter_int = fileList.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i <= Counter_int; i++)
            {
                FileList_Lst_Ordered.Add(fileList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault());
                fileList.Remove(fileList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            errorString = Ex.Message;
            Helpers.Helpers_TextFile.TextFile_WriteTo(Log_Filename, "Error Occured While Obtaining script list for folder " + folderId + ", full error: " + Ex.ToString());
        }
```

#### Initialise Service In GoogUtils.cs Helper

```
        public static DriveService InitService(ref string errorString)
                {
                    try {
                        var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = "###" };
                        var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                            {
                                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                                {
                                    ClientId = "###",
                                    ClientSecret = "###"
                                }
                            }),
                            "user",
                            token);

                        // Create Drive API service.
                        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                        {
                            HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                        });

                        return service;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        errorString = e.Message;
                    }

                    return null;
                }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. For a first question this is great, but please be clear about what your question actually is, and what your desired outcome is also for people who may be able to spot the problem, but are unfamiliar with what should be happening. Consider recapping at the end after your code blocks.

Comment: has the user revoked permission, has the refresh token expired?

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks for your suggestions this is the first thing I am checking.
User permissions are the first thing we checked, on the API console I checked the Client ID is registered and in Google Drive I checked the permissions for the folder and they look fine. Is there any other locations on the console I can check for folder permissions or any other tests that I can do?
The refresh token looks fine on authentication, when I create the service its fine it fails when I try and run the request.

Comment: you're confusing authentication with authorization. Is your app going through an auth flow, or is it relying on a stored refresh token. Have you tested the refresh token by using it as described here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks for the feedback. We are not on a stored refresh token. Although I am considering it based on this tutorial: https://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/ Before that I am looking at setting the access token to offline using C#.

Comment: Offline = Refresh Token

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve the problem. By re-writing the service so it uses GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync instead of GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow, I also am now loading the credentials from a JSON. See blow.
Thanks to all for your contributions and help:

```
 public static DriveService InitService(ref string errorString, string Log_Filename)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
            UserCredential credential;

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(credential_json))
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unable to Initialise Google Drives Service credentials not found.");
                Helpers.Helpers_TextFile.TextFile_WriteTo(Log_Filename, "Google Drive Init - Unable to Initialise Google Drives Service credentials not found.");
            }

            using (var stream = new FileStream(credential_json, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                if (credential.UserId == "user")
                {
                    Helpers.Helpers_TextFile.TextFile_WriteTo(Log_Filename, "Google Drive Init - Credentials file saved to: " + credPath);
                }
                else {
                    Helpers.Helpers_TextFile.TextFile_WriteTo(Log_Filename, "Google Drive Init - Unable to verify credentials.");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // Create Drive API service
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Validate Service
            if (service.Name == "drive" && service.ApplicationName == ApplicationName)
            {
                Helpers.Helpers_TextFile.TextFile_WriteTo(Log_Filename, "Google Drive Init - Google Service Created.");
            }
            else
            {
                Helpers.Helpers_TextFile.TextFile_WriteTo(Log_Filename, "Google Drive Init - Unable to create service.");
                return null;
            }

            return service;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("An Error Occured While Initialising Google Drives Service");
            System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(Ex.ToString());
            Helpers.Helpers_TextFile.TextFile_WriteTo(Log_Filename, "Google Drive Init - Error Occurred: " + Ex.ToString());
            errorString = Ex.Message;
        }

        return null;
    }
```